# How to bind a view property to a ViewModel property in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am having trouble figuring out how to dismiss a view that was presented fullscreen in SwiftUI.

On the sign in page, there is a tap to reset password option.  When the user taps there, another view appears.  The new view has a different ViewModel than that of the SignInView.

After an asynchronous operation to reset the password, I would like to dismiss the reset password view and go back to the SignInView.  An abbreviated version looks like this:

```
// SignInView

@State var isActive = false

var body: some View {
    Text("Forgot Password?  Tap to reset")
        .onTapGesture {
            isActive = true
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isActive, content: {
            ResetPasswordView(viewModel: ResetPasswordViewModel(), isActive: $isActive)
        })
}


// ResetPasswordView

@ObservedObject var viewModel: ResetPasswordViewModel

@Binding var isActive: Bool

init(viewModel: ResetPasswordViewModel, isActive: Binding<Bool>) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    self._isActive = isActive
}

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        viewModel.resetPassword()
    }, label: {
        Text("Done")
    })
}
```

Because the asynchronous password reset operation takes place in the ResetPasswordView's ViewModel, I want to be able to set the isActive to false once it's done and dismiss the ResetPasswordView.  But I don't know how to change the isActive from the ViewModel as it was passed directly to the view.

I'm very new to MVVM and not sure I am thinking about this the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have binded `isActive` properly. Now you just need to set it to `false`.
All you need is the following at the appropriate place:

```
isActive = false
```

One way is to let the `ViewModel` handle `isActive` directly.

#### Solution

```
class ResetPasswordViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Binding var isActive: Bool

  //...other viewModel variables
  
  init(/*...your other params*/ isActive: Binding<Bool>) {
    self._isActive = isActive
  }
  
  func resetPassword() {
    //...your logic
    isActive = false
  }
}
```

#### Example (in-use):

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var isActive = false
  
  var body: some View {
    Text("Forgot Password?  Tap to reset")
      .onTapGesture { isActive = true }
      .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isActive,
               content: {
                ResetPasswordView(viewModel: ResetPasswordViewModel(isActive: $isActive))
               })
  }
}

struct ResetPasswordView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ResetPasswordViewModel
  
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
      viewModel.resetPassword()
    }, label: {
      Text("Done")
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind view's property to viewmodel, viewmodel should manage the view all property state to publish to the view.

```
// SignInView
@ObservedObject var viewModel = CurrentPageViewModel()

var body: some View {
    Text("Forgot Password?  Tap to reset")
        .onTapGesture {
            viewModel.push()
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.isActive, content: {
            ResetPasswordView()
        })
}

class CurrentPageViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var isActive: Bool = false
  
  func push() {
    isActive = true
  }
}
```